# Get the unmatched user clockin vs user table

Tags: mysql-5.7

The `user` table contains users' information. The `clock_in` table contains the clockin of the users every day. I have been trying to check who is absent or not yet clocked in.

For example by 9:00 am, I should be able to check who has not clocked in yet. I have came up with the MySQL query and this what I have come up with so far after about 7 days now searching. The idea is to compare the user table to the users clockin today, if there is an unmatched (IS NULL) then that user has not clocked in today. Here is my updated query so far.

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users  
LEFT OUTER JOIN timecard  
  ON users.id = timecard.employment_id 
AND timecard.date='".$today."'
WHERE timecard.employment_id IS NULL and user.location = '".$location."' 
ORDER BY users.dept DESC
```

Please, I know Left Outer Join may be the right one according to the results of my search, need your advice

Comment: It looks to me that `t1.id` will **never** be `NULL`. You should be `JOIN`ing against a table with the dates of working days!

Comment: Thanks Verace, I will try...

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query).

Comment: p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: If $today is all you want, then just reverse your original join order.

Comment: Thanks Verace, it seems like the clause t2.date=$today is not working...I will check again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE personnel (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30));
```

populate it:

```
INSERT INTO personnel VALUES (1, 'Joe'), (2, 'Mary'), (3, 'Bill'), (4, 'Fred');
```

Create and populate the timecard table:

```
CREATE TABLE timecard (empid INTEGER, clockin_time DATETIME);

INSERT INTO timecard VALUES (1, '2019-08-28 08:00:18');
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES (2, '2019-08-28 08:00:28');
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES (3, '2019-08-28 08:00:28');
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES (1, '2019-08-29 08:00:03');
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES (4, '2019-08-29 08:04:04');
```

Note that only Joe and Fred have clocked in on the 29th of August - Mary and Joe haven't.

You can find the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=68925a4eec2193b58b5e558ceef89b0a).

So, first run this query to determine who clocked in on the 29th.

```
SELECT p.id AS the_id -- , p.name, t.empid -- remove -- to see results - shows thought process!
FROM timecard t
LEFT JOIN personnel p
  ON t.empid = p.id
WHERE DATE(t.clockin_time) = '2019-08-29'
ORDER BY p.id, t.clockin_time;
```

Result:

```
the_id
     1
     4
```

So, we see that Joe (id 1) and Fred (id 4) have clocked in.

Now, we need to find out the identities of those who **didn't** clock in. This is the list of people whose id's are **not** in the result of the first query. We obtain this by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM personnel pl
WHERE pl.id NOT IN
(
  SELECT p.id AS the_id
  FROM timecard t
  LEFT JOIN personnel p 
    ON t.empid = p.id
  WHERE DATE(t.clockin_time) = '2019-08-29'
  ORDER BY p.id, t.clockin_time
);
```

Result:

```
id  name
 2  Mary
 3  Bill
```

Something like this is probably what you require - if not, let me know. This construction allows you to do tallies of how many times person with id x was absent in a given month, day, using `BETWEEN` and lots more.... fun for all the family! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, just by reading the codes make sense. Amazing...I will get back to you ASAP

Comment: Thanks - if the solution is good for you, you could upvote it and/or mark it correct? :-)

Comment: Thank Verace, Here is my query SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT timecard.* FROM timecard  LEFT JOIN users on timecard.employment_id = users.id
WHERE timecard.date='".$today."'  order by users.dept) an error " Operand should contain 1 column(s) " can you help me here please

Comment: If the timecard table has more than one field (i.e. id), I fail to see how your query could work. Copy my fiddle and run your first tests on that data. In the meantime, if you found my answer helpful, you can upvote it. You could also mark it as correct for the question as asked.

Comment: Verace, I have updated my answer, it works but takes time to get the query from DB, what do you think?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with a small amount of sample data and your desired result. A `LETT OUTER`  join is not necessary. An ordinary join will work as I've shown!